# How to make electron app configurable in the release version?

Tags: angular, electron, config, electron-builder

I have created an electron app having angular as frontend.And in backend i have used MySql db. I want to do following things after i make release version of this app:-

1. Make a json file in the release directory which contains info like db name,password,port,or any other info etc.
   I want this file to work as a config file which can be edited by end user (In the release version)

The changes that users make in the file should be reflected in my app too
Like changing the whole database etc
I am not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: The code concerning file operations is OS related so you should put it in your main process.
The editing code will be an UI shown to the user. On the submit  of the edit you renderer process will send an IPC message to the main with any change in the payload of the message

Comment: I am avoiding this on the UI part, as i just want to make the changes in the file only. But thanks a lot!

Comment: So If I understand well you just need a .ini file that  the user can access and modify with an editor outside of the app. The app during loading will by your main.js file load this file parse it to look after the db parameters for example and assign the value to your database host, user etc... Is it your requirement? If so the aswer below is the right one

Comment: @AlainBUFERNE yeah that is what my requirements are..but you said .ini file...i can achieve this with any file ig for e.g json,env,txt etc..

Comment: Sure I said .ini because historically it was a format used in windows app but you can use which format you want and use either a node module or your own to parse it and recover the data.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to generate your `json` config file during your build process (unless you generate the users initial username, password , database name, etc during any application registration / purchase process). Instead, make this function part of your applications start-up / first run code.

During the initialisation phase of your application starting, look for existence of the `json` config file.

> The best place for this file to be stored is in the user’s data directory, appended by your applications name. See [app.getPath('userData')](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appgetpathname) for more information.

If the `json` config file **exists**, load it (obviously in your main process) and reference it's values as per normal.

If the file does **not exist** (IE: First run), create it with default values. You can also give the user (if you want) the option to change the default values during the first run by popping up a dialog (or something similar) with the appropriate config fields.

The `json` config values should be changeable by your applications UI for users who are not comfortable editing the `json` config file directly.

Those who do edit the `json` config file directly will see their changes take effect immediately upon application restart. You could also make any changes hot reloadable though that would require a file watcher, etc (or a manual 'reload' button in the UI).

If the `json` config file is allowed to be edited by the user, you **should** validate the structure and content of the file during application start-up (or after hot reloading), else any malformed `json` config file would crash your application.